# Insert worksheet at specified index in existing Excel file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Is there a way to insert a worksheet at a specified index using Pandas? With the code below, when adding a dataframe as a new worksheet, it gets added after the last sheet in the existing Excel file. What if I want to insert it at say index 1?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

f = 'existing_file.xlsx'
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':['A','B'], 'word': ['C','D']})

book = load_workbook(f)    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: As per the pandas documentation, there is no option to specify the index while creating new sheets. But if you really need it so, you will have to create another workbook by iterating over the sheets from the existing workbook in the order you need.

Comment: Just use the openpyxl utilities to put the dataframe where you want. It's all documented.